# problem with count of unique characters in filtered rows VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I want to count the cells of a column that is filtered and has repeated numbers.
in excel I use this formula and it works perfectly.

```
Selection.FormulaArray ="SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(A2,ROW(A2:A6)-ROW(A2),,1)), IF(A2:A6<>"""",MATCH(""~""&A2:A6,A2:A6&"""",0))),ROW(A2:A6)-ROW(A2)+1),1))"
```

I want to do it in VBA to be able to change the ranges where I apply the formula, it gives me an error because "WorksheetFunction" does not work with IF.

```
xCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(A2,ROW(A2:A6)-ROW(A2),,1)), IF(A2:A6<>"""",MATCH(""~""&A2:A6,A2:A6&"""",0))),ROW(A2:A6)-ROW(A2)+1),1))
```

What I can do ?

use the recommendation and it gives me an error

```
NUM = 6
ActiveSheet.Evaluate ("=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(A2,ROW(A2:A") & NUM(")-ROW(A2),,1)), IF(A2:A6<>"""",MATCH(""~""&A2:A6,A2:A6&"""",0))),ROW(A2:A6)-ROW(A2)+1),1))")
```

Comment: Use `ActiveSheet.Evaluate(...)` with the original formula as text, doubling up inner quotes.

Comment: gives me error =(

Comment: Please [edit] your question with your attempt.